# how to send variable from ajax to FLASK python?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm new in python, now I want use send variable from ajax to python with FLASK.

My html

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Process this form?")){
            var form=$('#form2').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:5000/",
                method:"POST",
                data:form,
                success:function(){
                    $('#form2')[0].reset();
                    alert('Process Success');
                } 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Python

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
'''def round_up(n, decimals=0): 
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals 
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier'''
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    clicked=None
    if request.method == "POST":
        clicked=request.json['data']
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Regards,
Andri

Comment: You’re more or less doing it. What do you get and what’s the issue with this code?

Comment: @deceze Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not a programming language bounded thing, it is more general than this. You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjozQOaGt1k) video for better understanding. After that you can check [this](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) link which will help you to manage CORS for your Flask application.